# How to classify date and time written cell to 3 groups?

Tags: excel

Cells are like this: 15.06.15 06:24
And I want to sort it to 3 groups by using the time. For example if it's between 08:00-16:00 neighbor cell must be 1, if its between 16:00-24:00 it will be 2 etc. Are there any way to do it?

Comment: Are the cells formatted as text or date/time?

Comment: Its custom formatted as dd.mm.yy hh:mm

Comment: Take a look at the Right and Left function. That way you can extract the HH part of your string, and wrap that in an IF statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF((Left(Right(A1,5),2)>16),2,IF((Left(Right(A1,5),2)>8),1,0)
```

Should work when your number is in `A1`